# how to save mixed sort?

Tags: swift, core-data

From the list in which the words are located, I need to display them in a mixed state.
To do this, I added a shuffle sort field to the entity

```
func setShuffleWords(id: UUID?) -> [CoreWord]? {
    guard let id = id else { return nil }
    let requestWords = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "CoreWord")
    requestWords.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY dictionary.id == %@", id as CVarArg)
    var coreWords: [CoreWord]?
    if let result = try? managedContext.fetch(requestWords) as? [CoreWord] {
        let words = result.shuffled()
        for (index, value) in words.enumerated() {
            if value.value(forKey: "shuffle") != nil {
                value.setValue(index, forKey: "shuffle")
            }
        }
        coreWords = words
    }
    save()
    return coreWords
}

func getShuffleWords(id: UUID?) -> [CoreWord]? {
    guard let id = id else { return nil }
    let requestWords = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "CoreWord")
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "shuffle", ascending: true)
    requestWords.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY dictionary.id == %@", id as CVarArg)
    requestWords.sortDescriptors = [sort]
    do {
        let result = try managedContext.fetch(requestWords)
        return result as? [CoreWord]
    } catch let error {
        fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

[image: graph]

But, the problem is that if I mix up another list where this word is, then the value is rewritten and it will change its position everywhere.
How to keep mixed order in a specific list?

Answer (score 1):

In this situation you need to replace your many-many relationship with an intermediate entity.  Let’s call that entity a Listing.  It will represent the listing of a particular word in a particular group, so each Listing should have a to-one relationship to CoreWord and a to-one relationship to CoreGroup.  In each case the inverse (which you might call “listings”) should be to-many.  The Listing entity should have (at least) one attribute, shuffle, which represents the sequence of a particular word on a particular group.

Life generally gets more complicated, because you have to create and manage these intermediate objects rather than just working the Word and Group objects and their relationships.